# What condition/action add to workflow so it sends a 72 hour reminder?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I already created a calculated column called Reminder in my custom list that calculates the date 72 hours later after the item is created (ex. Item created 6/13/2016, Reminder column shows 6/16/2016). I have 3 stages (divided by department) in a workflow, what condition/action can I add in each stage that sends a reminder to that department that there's an item idle for more than 72 hours? I want them to get that reminder only once.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pause for duration` and then check whether the user has completed their action.

Insert your cursor inside the main step (see red line in pic) then click or type "Parallel Block" to add that action. Then add steps inside the "The following actions will run in parallel" section.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how can I add the PAUSE and it sending the reminder email without breaking the rest of the workflow.

Comment: You can use it in a parallel step

Comment: How can I move the workflow to the next stage if the item has been approved without having to wait for the pause to end?

Comment: If your logic to move to the next stage is parallel to the logic to wait, then the pause will not halt your workflow. Add a parallel block inside one of your steps. Then put two steps inside the parallel block. Put your actions into one of the steps. Put the pause inside the other. Search the web if you need more instructions for parallel blocks.

Comment: See screenshot I added to my post

Answer (score 1):

You should use **PAUSE** condition for 72 hours & check the condition for the same. Please check below image for reference.

[image]

**Note:-**

It is just for an example i have created for other user.

[Check my answer here if you can get some help from there.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/183745/how-to-send-an-email-when-an-items-status-has-been-in-pending-for-too-long)

Comment: Should I create a new workflow or I add the PAUSE at the beginning of the Stage?

Comment: You should mention the pause in your workflow after every department's conditions of created item.

Comment: So it could be an Else in after the conditions but before the transition?

Comment: Yes you can put it in there.

Comment: One of the conditions I'm using is Wait for Item to Change, this won't affect the Pause?

Comment: You should add else part where you are checking the status by wait & put the pause for 72 hours than send an email after it. So user will be notified for the same after 72 hours.

Comment: I hope than i understand your requirement correctly. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Did you get it working for you?

Comment: Not yet, to be honest I have no idea how to add it without breaking the workflow...

Comment: It is hard for me to show you here that how can you add the pause in the workflow in your scenario. As you are the best person who knows the conditions of the workflow better than others. I gave my best effort to help you as **Pause** is the condition you should use. Now its on you man.

Comment: I think you should do it by your own as you are the best person who knows the application. I can guide you for the solution not more than than so i hope I helped you for the same... :)

Comment: can you please give me some points for sake of my reputation?

Comment: How I do that? Cick the up arrow? I'm new here lol

Comment: Yes it is the only way by clicking the up arrow...

Comment: Did you get it? If not than please refer this...http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I require 15 reputation to vote but once I get there I'll upvote you, you have been very helpful